# Code not giving output

Tags: php

I have been brainstorming with this piece of code since a very long time but no success.

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$question = $_GET['question'];
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("contact");
$query ="INSERT INTO contactus (name, email, question) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$question."')";
$done=mysql_query($query); 
echo "Hello $name {$_GET["name"]}";
echo "\nYour query $question {$_GET["question"]}";
```

Comment: what are you expecting as output? that code looks fine

Comment: Please descripe where you have your code, and have you even a start php tag

Comment: Please show the URL you use to request the script. I guess you have an opening php tag, do you?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability and a XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Are you sure the $_GET variables are set? You should also escape your varibales $name, $email and $question.

Comment: Is this in relation to an html page or an ajax request?

Comment: Now I have edited the code properly. Can you please tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Replace quotes around name and question with single quotes:

```
echo "Hello $name {$_GET['name']}";

echo "\nYour query $question {$_GET['question']}";
```

Since you already define the string with double quotes, use single quotes to specify a string within your string.

Answer (score 0):

If you use double quotes you can also use the PHP3-esque notation without curly braces:

```
echo "\nYour query $question $_GET[question]";
```

Note the lack of quotes around the array key. This syntax is *only valid within double quotes*, though. In normal PHP context you do need them.

Answer (score -1):

another option:

```
echo "hello" . $name . "{" .$_GET['name']."}"; ....
```